# How would I either mock java.net.URL or programatically set a spring bean to accept a constructor parameter?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking

**Background**
I am working on an application suite in Java where I am making calls into different subsystems via HTTP post / get. In my drive to have everything unit tested I have run into a problem where I could not use [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to mock directly since the `URL` class is `final`.

**Where I am at**
Since the `URL` class cannot be mocked I decided to create a wrapper class and only expose the methods of the `URL` class that I was using. You can find that class below. This seemed to work well until I began to try to set my beans in the test context.

**UrlWrapper**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class UrlWrapper {

    URL url;

    public UrlWrapper(String spec) throws MalformedURLException{
        url = new URL(spec);
    }

    public URLConnection openConnection() throws IOException{
        return url.openConnection();
    }

}
```

**Unit Test Method**

```
@Test
public final void testToMockConstructorInjectedBean()
        throws IOException {
    GenericApplicationContext mockContext = new GenericApplicationContext();

    // Create our mock controller
    UrlWrapper mockUrl = mock(UrlWrapper.class);

    // Set the mock object in the context
    mockContext.refresh();
    mockContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("url", mockUrl);
    UrlWrapper mock = null;
    mock = (UrlWrapper)mockContext.getBean("url"); // <-- Works
    mock = (UrlWrapper)mockContext.getBean("url", "http://google.com/"); // <-- Fails.
}
```

**The question**
What I would really love is to figure how how to get the line that "fails" in the unit test to work properly. This would impact the rest of the code the least and would be ideal. Another option I could take, but to me feels like a code smell, is to modify my wrapper to have a set method that accepts a `String` and creates a new `URL` object internally. What is the 'normal' proper way to unit test code that either uses URL? Also, how would you mock a context for unit testing that accepts a constructor parameter during injection?

## Edit 1

---

**Context Provider**

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class ContextProvider {
    private static ApplicationContext appContext;

    public static void setContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        appContext = context;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        if (appContext == null) {
            appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        }

        return appContext;
    }
}
```

**Sample Usage outside of a unit test**

```
public boolean post() throws IOException {
    UrlWrapper url;

    // Get my URL from the available context (either 'live' or 'test' context)
    url = (UrlWrapper) ContextProvider.getContext().getBean("url", requestUrl);

    /* More code here omitted for brevity */
}
```

Comment: I suppose your end result would be to have the `openConnection` method return a mocked `URLConnection`?

Comment: Eventually that is where I'll be going for this specific case. I was also looking for an answer to the more generic question concerning the constructor parameter for any other future tests I may run into.

Comment: It seems to me that it might be more reasonable to register a  Spy as a bean to the application context rather than a Mock. That way you can create the object any way you want then only stub the methods that you actually want to change.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the pointer. I'll definitely research the Spy thing and try that out. Is there somewhere you could point me to start learning about Spys in the context of Spring/Mockito? I did a little quick googling and nothing seemed promising.

Comment: I added it as answer below for future readers to easily find without having to read the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to mock a bean properly at run time that takes constructor parameters. The complexity here lies in that the bean is scoped to a prototype so I had to do some reading on the IoC container inside of spring. I hope that this helps anyone that may be as confused as I was when I started down this path.

**This is my testApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <bean name="serviceLocator" class="com.maddonkeysoftware.donkeydesktopmonitor.MockBeanProvider">
        <!-- inject any dependencies required by this locator bean -->
    </bean>

    <bean name="url" factory-bean="serviceLocator" factory-method="fetchMockUrl" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg value="0"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Here is the provider.**

```
package com.maddonkeysoftware.donkeydesktopmonitor;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import com.maddonkeysoftware.donkeydesktopmonitor.requests.UrlWrapper;

public class MockBeanProvider {

    private static Queue<UrlWrapper> urlWrapperQueue = new LinkedList<UrlWrapper>();

    private MockBeanProvider() {}

    public static void enqueueMockUrl(UrlWrapper mock){
        urlWrapperQueue.add(mock);
    }

    public Object fetchMockUrl(String args) {
        return urlWrapperQueue.poll();
    }
}
```

**Here is the final version of my unit test.**

```
    @Test
public final void baseRequest_PostResponseReturned()
        throws IOException {

    // NOTE: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html
    // Go to the section 4.3.1 and look at the factory for providing custom beans.

    // Create our mock controller
    UrlWrapper mockUrl = mock(UrlWrapper.class);
    URLConnection mockUrlConn = mock(URLConnection.class);

    // set up the mockUrl
    when(mockUrl.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockUrlConn);
    when(mockUrlConn.getInputStream()).thenReturn(IOUtils.toInputStream("Success"));
    when(mockUrlConn.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(new PipedOutputStream(new PipedInputStream()));

    MockBeanProvider.enqueueMockUrl(mockUrl);

    // Set our mock context into our application.
    com.maddonkeysoftware.donkeydesktopmonitor.ContextProvider.setContext(new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("testApplicationContext.xml"));

    MockBeanProvider p = (MockBeanProvider)ContextProvider.getContext().getBean("serviceLocator");

    // Create our object under test.
    AddImageRequest request = new AddImageRequest();
    request.setRequestUrl("http://testUrl.com");
    boolean result = request.post();

    // Verify that everything was called as expected.
    assertTrue(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that in your case you take a look at Mockito's `Spy`. [Here](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mockito.googlecode.com%2Fhg%2Flatest%2Forg%2Fmockito%2FSpy.html&ei=PrjsU4mxIufY0QX31IAo&usg=AFQjCNGBSX-rR2ZcSBZtu637g9zeixkWKw&sig2=CnD5pQ-4WUv1_icSr9AYVQ) is the javadoc and [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/10/13/effective-mockito-part-3/) is a tutorial of it's use.

In your case you would create a spy of the real URLWrapper object, and then perform whatever other interaction is needed.

```
@Test
public final void testToMockConstructorInjectedBean()
        throws IOException {
    GenericApplicationContext mockContext = new GenericApplicationContext();

    // Create our mock controller
    UrlWrapper spyUrl = spy(new URLWrapper("http://google.com"));

    // Set the mock object in the context
    mockContext.refresh();
    mockContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("url", spyUrl);
    UrlWrapper spy = null;
    spy = (UrlWrapper)mockContext.getBean("url");
}
```

In this case you create the spy with the specified URL, and then just register that object as the bean for the class.

**UPDATE**

In my opinion

`url = (UrlWrapper) ContextProvider.getContext().getBean("url", requestUrl);`

is to restrictive in the test code. Code like this would mean that the beans need to be created in a specific way (a static factory method) in order to be able to be created as the test expects. What I suggest is that you populate the Spring context with a bean that already contains the desired behavior, and then just use `getBean` without arguments

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this will work. In other sections of the code I have a context provider that either creates a new context via an XML file or uses the context provided by the unit test. In the code that calls this context provider it calls `getBean("url", memberVarString);`. What I'm getting at here is that using mockContext with just `.getBean("url");` is not an option for me unless I move to some sort of parameter injection.

Comment: It would be good if you updated your question showing an example of where the present solution wouldn't work. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem. I just tossed some more example code in there under the section "Edit 1". I apologize for not including this the first time as I thought I was being clear. Thanks for the help up to this point though! It's very nice having someone to bounce this stuff off of.

Comment: The code `getBean("url", requestUrl)` assumes that there is a class like `URLWrapperFactoryBean` that has a static method that return a new instance of `URLWrapper` while taking the `requestUrl` as an input. That test code seems very restricting. My opinion is to change the test code to allow for more flexible bean creation

Comment: How would you suggest changing it? `getBean` is a method provided to me by [Spring](http://spring.io/). I'm not sure I follow how to modify the test code to allow the bean to be created in a more flexible manner. Did you possibly mean to say "My opinion is to change the code that is under test to allow for more flexible bean creation"? If that's the case then I think I am with you and I need to start entering "refactor land" since what I am trying to do doesn't seem possible with spring at runtime.

Comment: What am saying is that `url = (UrlWrapper) ContextProvider.getContext().getBean("url", requestUrl);` is to restrictive in the test code. Code like this would mean that the beans need to be created in a specific way in order to be able to be created as the test expects. What I suggest is that you populate the Spring context with a bean that already contains the desired behavior, and then just use `getBean` without arguments